# How to preg_replace repeating words

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to preg_replace repeating words but the following leaves some words. I think it only take the first two.

```
<?php
$text ='around background background background background';
$non_repeat = preg_replace("/\b(\w+)\s+\\1\b/i", "$1", $text);
echo $non_repeat;
?>
```

How to i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below regex would replace all the background strings with a single background string,

```
\b(\w+)(?:\s\1)+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eJ9fY2/3)

Your PHP code would be,

```
<?php
$text ='around background background background background';
$non_repeat = preg_replace("/\b(\w+)(?:\s\\1)+/i", "$1", $text);
echo $non_repeat;
?>  //=> around background
```

[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/Rf30D9)

Answer (score 2):

To eliminate all the repeated words, use this:

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~\b(\w+)\K\b(?:\s*\1)+~', '', $yourstring);
```

See the second colored group in [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/44).

**Explanation**

- `\b` is the opening word boundary
- `(\w+)` captures the word to Group 1
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `\b` is the closing word boundary
- `(?:\s*\1)+` matches optional spaces then Group 1, one or more times
- we replace this with the empty string

Comment: FYI: added demo and explanation. :)